# How to set all bits of a bitfield member to 1

Tags: c++, c++11

The question is pretty simple. Given

```
struct Foo{
    bool     : 1;
    bool     : 1;
    int bar  : sizeof(int) * 8 - 2;
};
```

How can I set all bits of bar to 1, without a warning?

Obviously I can do `auto v = Foo(); v.bar = ~0;` but GCC gives me this:

```
warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
```

I have tried a couple of ways, but it always renders a warning...

Comment: Why do you need a bit-field? (Btw, there is no guarantee your structure won't end up containing too bools and an int).

Comment: M.b. u can use memset() ?

Comment: What do you get for `v.bar = UINT_MAX;` ?

Comment: Note: the warning indicates that the bitfield is unsigned; use `signed int bar` if you specifically want a signed field.

Comment: I'd use std::bitset instead of non-portable, problematic bit-fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `~0` (which is always a full `int`), but `~v.bar`, which is the right size and can be combined like so:

```
v.bar |= ~v.bar; // or,
v.bar ^= ~v.bar;
```

should do the trick, for any size.

Unfortunately you can't nicely wrap it in a function since you can't bind references to bitfields. You'd either need to make it a function on `Foo&`, or use a macro.

PS. I tried this quickly before posting with [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/), and just re-checked locally with GCC (g++) 5.3.1 and 6.2.0 - neither issue any diagnostic with `-Wall`.

PPS.

With this test code, GCC produces a diagnostic only for the unsigned member:

```
struct Foo {
  int i : 2;
  unsigned int u : 30;
};

void bar() {
  Foo f {0, 0};
  f.i ^= ~f.i; // OK
  f.u |= ~f.u; /* warning:
    large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
  */
}
```

So although I'd also usually prefer unsigned integers for bitfields or for bitwise manipulation, g++ is happier and quieter with `int` here.

Comment: `g++` as of 6.0.1 still warns about these constructs (`gcc` doesn't).

Comment: `clang 3.8` doesn't warn

Comment: Note: `Foo v; v.bar |= ~v.bar;` would be UB due to using uninitialized variable. This code relies on `v.bar` having previously been initialized, as it was in OP's code.  And if you know it was zero-initialized then `v.bar = ~v.bar;` would suffice.

Comment: Also, if `v.bar` is narrower than `int` (as in this case), the integral promotions will promote it to `int` before applying the `~` operator

Comment: @n.m yeah I know - just a piece of information - there is no such thing as too much knowledge :) Maybe author will try to switch to clang ?

Comment: What warning does g++ 6.0.1 give you? I don't get anything with the versions I tried.

Comment: @Useless Same warning as OP is citing, but the code is not identical, I have explicitly declared `bar` as `unsigned int` (any bit-manipulating  data should be unsigned).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me for unsigned types. Note that all bit-fiddling should be done with unsigned types, unless you're OK with undefined behaviour.

```
...
   unsigned int bar  : sizeof(int) * 8 - 2;
...

template <typename T, unsigned n>
constexpr T onebits()
{
    return 1 | (((1 << (n-2)) - 1) << 1);
}

v.bar = onebits<unsigned, sizeof(int) * 8 - 2>();
```

Comment: That is very neat as well, thank you for your contribution!